# React Native - Como mostrar o valor salvo com AsyncStorage em um componente Text

Tags: react-native

Gostaria muito de conseguir estar renderizando em um componente de texto o valor salvo e alterado com o `Async Storage`.

Em `showData` eu consigo obter o novo valor com:

```
console.log(`novo valor: ${newValue}`)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém não consigo renderizar o valor em tela em:

```
<Text>Mostrar novo valor aqui: {/* ${newValue} */}</Text>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em minhas tentativas obtive:

```
[Fri Jan 15 2021 22:05:33.510]ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: newValue
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Alert
} from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

export default function Home() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('00')

  const saveData = async () => {
    var newValue = value

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('newValue', JSON.stringify(newValue))

    Alert.alert('Dados salvos com sucesso!')
  }

  const showData = async () => {
    var json = await AsyncStorage.getItem('newValue')
    var newValue = JSON.parse(json)

    console.log(
      `novo valor: ${newValue}`
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Alterar valor: </Text>
        <TextInput value={value}
          onChangeText={text => setValue(text)} />

        <Text>Mostrar novo valor aqui: {/* ${newValue} */}</Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveData}>
        <Text>Salvar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={showData}>
        <Text>Mostrar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

Estou começando com React Native, agradeço quem puder ajudar!

Comment: `newValue` so existe dentor do contexto da funcao `showData`. Nao seria melhor criar um estado para `newValue` (`const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState('00')`), atualizar ele com valor do storage na hora da chamar a funcao `showData`?

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de criar um estado chamado `newValue` para que pudesse alterar o valor de forma visual, e formatá-lo corretamente dentro da tag `Text`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Alert
} from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

export default function Home() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('00')
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(null)

  const saveData = async () => {
    var newValue = value

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('newValue', JSON.stringify(newValue))

    Alert.alert('Dados salvos com sucesso!')
  }

  const showData = async () => {
    var json = await AsyncStorage.getItem('newValue')
    setNewValue(JSON.parse(json))
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Alterar valor: </Text>
        <TextInput value={value}
          onChangeText={text => setValue(text)} />

        <Text>Mostrar novo valor aqui: {newValue}</Text>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveData}>
        <Text>Salvar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={showData}>
        <Text>Mostrar</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```